# Do invisible elements in DOM decrease performance?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, dom

I'm having quite a lot of issues with jQuery Mobile. We're currently loading the whole page (all of its sections) into the same `index.html`. This means the project's running really slow.

So, after reading [this](http://www.ignitersworld.com/blogs/things-to-take-care-while-developing-a-phonegap-app/), I noticed that one of the improvements he suggests (it's focused on Cordova/Phonegap, which is actually the endpoint of the website I'm doing) is to keep DOM parts in variables instead of the root DOM itself.

However, after reading all of this, and checking my current DOM, I basically noticed that all of the contents aren't visible at all (`display:none`), so there's something that really concerns me before starting doing a major change of this kind.

**Do invisible elements in DOM actually decrease performance?**

And, if I cas ask as well:

**Is "loading DOMs from variables" dynamically going to help?**

Comment: If your webapp is big (more than 5 pages) It's better to go for Single Page Model (each page in a separate file).

Comment: It's what I imagined

Comment: @omar Even if they would be in a separate file, do you think the problem of slow performance will be solved? Lets take a case where there are more than 5 pages and there are separate files. The user uses the application such that the all the files are loaded during the navigation of the entire app. Would it not still slow the performance of the App?

Comment: @frank external pages are removed once navigated away, they are not cached by default. First page is always present in DOM in addition to "active" external page. To speed up navigation, external pages can be preloaded and/or peefetched before hand to speed up navigation.

Comment: @frank that's what @Omar says. jQuery mobile works in a way that it always has a visible page, and it keeps changing it dynamically when you hit `.pagecontainer('change')`.